# Sorting the same column by conditions applied from other columns

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I am really struggling to solve the following sorting of a data frame. Appreciate help on this.
Basically, I have the following dataframe:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
a       0.55    0.22    1
a        0.7    0.16    1
b       0.88    0.18    2
b        0.9    0.23    2
b        0.6    0.33    2
c        0.5    0.11    3
c       0.23    0.05    3
d        0.4    -0.15   3
b        0.65   0.1     1
```

I want my dataframe to be sorted depending on the value of col1. If col1 value is equal to a or b, then I want to sort the dataframe by col2 in descending order, if my col1 value equals to c or d, then I want my dataframe to be sorted by col3.
The output should look like this:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
b        0.9    0.23    2
b       0.88    0.18    2
a        0.7    0.16    1
b        0.65   0.33    2
b        0.6    0.1     1
a       0.55    0.22    1
c        0.5    0.11    3
c       0.23    0.05    3
d        0.4    -0.15   3
```

I don't mind any help either in pandas or pythonic form.
Thanks

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you don't want to sort by col1 at all, but only by col2 or col3 depending on the case?

Comment: Yes, I only want to sort by col2 and col3

Answer (score 1):

You could create an additional column that takes values from either `col2` or `col3` based on the value in `col1` and then sort on that -

```
df.loc[:, 'sort_col'] = df['col1'].isin(['a', 'b']) * df['col2'] + df['col1'].isin(['c', 'd']) * df['col3']
df = df.sort_values(by=['sort_col'], ascending=False)
df

#   col1  col2  col3  col4  sort_col
#3    b  0.90  0.23     2      0.90
#2    b  0.88  0.18     2      0.88
#1    a  0.70  0.16     1      0.70
#8    b  0.65  0.10     1      0.65
#4    b  0.60  0.33     2      0.60
#0    a  0.55  0.22     1      0.55
#5    c  0.50  0.11     3      0.11
#6    c  0.23  0.05     3      0.05
#7    d  0.40 -0.15     3     -0.15
```

Comment: Thanks Mortz. I appreciate it.